# openNMS fetch nodes from DNS server

Tags: opennms

I am trying to get openNMS (v1.12) to fetch the list of nodes from DNS server.
First, I tried to add `requisition-def` in my `provisiond-configuration.xml` with `dns://mydnsServerIP/myZone` and following, I executed:

`/opt/opennms/bin/send-event.pl uei.opennms.org/internal/reloadDaemonConfig --parm 'daemonName Provisiond'`

to avoid restarting. Nothing happened.

Following, I tried to add the dns URL in `configure discovery` URL in the admin page. After saving, `discovery.log` started having entries like this:

```
2014-02-24 20:54:53,919 WARN  [OpenNMS.Discovery-Thread] DiscoveryConfigFactory: 
Unknown host '<node building="MYZONE_HERE" foreign-id="520105224" 
node-label="CORRECTNODELABEL_HERE">' inside discovery include file: 
address ignored

2014-02-24 20:54:53,920 WARN  [OpenNMS.Discovery-Thread] DiscoveryConfigFactory: 
Unknown host '<interface descr="DNS-AAAA" ip-addr="IPV6_HERE" managed="true" status="1"     
snmp-primary="P">' inside discovery include file: address ignored

2014-02-24 20:54:53,922 WARN  [OpenNMS.Discovery-Thread] DiscoveryConfigFactory: 
Unknown host '<monitored-service service-name="SNMP"/>' inside discovery include 
file: address ignored

2014-02-24 20:54:53,925 WARN  [OpenNMS.Discovery-Thread] DiscoveryConfigFactory: 
Unknown host '<monitored-service service-name="ICMP"/>' inside discovery include 
file: address ignored

2014-02-24 20:54:53,927 WARN  [OpenNMS.Discovery-Thread] DiscoveryConfigFactory: 
Unknown host '</interface>' inside discovery include file: address ignored
2014-02-24 20:54:53,929 WARN  [OpenNMS.Discovery-Thread] DiscoveryConfigFactory: 
Unknown host '</node>' inside discovery include file: address ignored
```

It there anything else I have to do to get it to auto discover nodes from DNS server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OpenNMS server that is initiating the provisioning via a DNS import must be allowed to perform a zone transfer. You can test it with the following from your OpenNMS server console.

```
dig -t AXFR @<dnsServer> <zone>
```

If that fails the provisioning will fail.

Also you need to create a provisioning group first.

See more here: http://www.opennms.org/wiki/DNS_Importing